# Identify a Breakpoint by Breakpoint Number Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

While using the debugger in Xcode, I got the following error:

```
"Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 6.3"
```

So, I'd like to remove breakpoint 6.3.  How can I figure out which one has the number 6.3? I have looked in the breakpoint summary panel, tried right clicking on each one, but I don't see any way to identify each these number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems no way to identify the breakpoints by number in the Xcode Breakpoint Navigator.

However, you can easily remove the breakpoint in the debugger console. In your case "6" is the breakpoint number and "3" is one of the breakpoint locations.

```
breakpoint list
```

shows all breakpoints.

```
breakpoint delete 6
```

deletes breakpoint 6 (with all locations).

```
breakpoint disable 6.3
```

disables only location 3 of breakpoint 6.